# Use nullable value if it HasValue

Tags: c#, .net

Say, I have `int? number`. And I need to do the following:

```
if (number.HasValue)
{
    // use number.Value in any way. for example:
    return number.Value;
}
else
{
    return 0; // or another literal or constant value
}
```

Is there any existing method that does the listed above?

Comment: Odd that it looks like the OP managed to answer their question in the same second as it was posted.  Since then they appear to have incorporated the _other_ answer into their own.  Must be a browser bug on my end.

Comment: Why did you ask this question? The answer is found in the main MSDN documentation for nullable types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx What makes you think this is going to be valuable for future visitors?

Comment: I see such code really very often in many projects because developers know the `.HasValue` and `.Value` properties and use them in the cases like I posted in question. They don't really know that there is more usable alternative. So I decided to bring an additional piece of light on that question by sharing the knowledge in Q&A style. Was it not a good idea?

Comment: Not a good idea when the effort required to find the answer is a Google search for: `c# default for null`

Comment: There's little value in a question that is trivially answered by reading the documentation. And it's not hard to find the documentation. Anyone who uses nullable types know what they are called. At which point you cannot fail to find the docs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) is for:

```
return number ?? 6;
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is what you need - [Nullable.GetValueOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d6d4f1d.aspx).

Example:

```
return number.GetValueOrDefault();
```

You can specify will be the **default** value in case of `number.HasValue == false`. In the fists example it is `default(int)` = `0`:

```
return number.GetValueOrDefault(5);
```

Thanks to [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) for comment. It's also possible to do:

```
return number ?? 5;
```

As I found compiler replaces `number == null` style code with `number.HasValue` so you can use the option you prefer or your coding guidelines dictate.

Comment: Null-coalescing operator is the answer. If you are going to answer your own question, it really ought to be a question that hasn't already been answered loads of times, and it you ought to get the answer right.

Comment: They just linked to the wrong article - the override mentioned in the answer is here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d6d4f1d.aspx